# how to create / append list in python to mysql using pyodbc after parse xml

Tags: python, xml, parsing, odbc

I need to parse xml (xmldata) from one database ( sql server ) then extract and load them up to a clean table and store them to another database ( mysql ) using python

Here's my code

```
import pyodbc
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO


con_c = pyodbc.connect('DSN=database1;Database=y;UID=x;PWD=y')
con_a = pyodbc.connect('DSN=database2;Database=x;UID=x;PWD=y')

cur_a = con_a.cursor() 
cur_c = con_c.cursor() 

cur_c.execute("""
select top 100
id,
xmldata
from table1
""")

rows_c = cur_c.fetchall()
for row in rows_c:

     x = str(row.xmldata)
     root = etree.fromstring(x)                  
     build_text_list = etree.XPath("//text()")   
     texts = build_text_list(root)              

     print((texts))
```

Now.. here's what I am stuck with. "texts" is now "list" of value ... that I can print 
[scott,xx,...]
them out, but how can I store the lists into Database2

[image]

Comment: yes I do , I can do create table , but not sure how to pass through "texts" ( python list per each ID ) into macro variable or something ? please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
con_a.execute("INSERT INTO table2 (variable1, variable2) VALUES(?, ?)", *texts[:2])
con_a.commit()
```

or use [executemany](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executemany)

```
params = [ ('A', 1), ('B', 2) ]
con_a.executemany("insert into t(name, id) values (?, ?)", params)
con_a.commit()
```

Some additional thoughts:

- variable1, variable2 and so on are bad choices for column names.
- There may be limits on how many column names and escape parameters (the question marks) you can use.
- 300 columns in one table seems like an awful lot and can be a sign of bad design.

So I hope you will keep your tables [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and give the table's columns meaningful names. Also, be aware there's an easier to use Mysql adaptor for python called MySQLdb. It lets you avoid the connection string trouble.

Comment: Thank you moter, I have to try that out. what would be the best approach in this situation, not only have have lots of variables , this is also huge data as well, I'm dealing with 60 millions record. Hopefully the code will finish running before I get old.

Comment: Think really long and hard about a good database design. Divide the data into logical compounds, e.g. an address may have a street, house nr., zip code. So you have a table 'address' and the address rows you can link to other rows in other tables via foreign key. The hyperlink I posted does a good job of explaining the concept.

Comment: cool, I will check that out. I'm usually an end user. But this is definitely help. Thank you so much.